# Offsite web-based tool commonly used by developers

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

On SO is allowed to ask about a tools commonly used by programmers. This is ok and I in most of time I can correctly distinguish when the question is more about the *configuration* (so belong to SU) or more about *programming*.

My question is about the *offsite, web based tools used by programmers*, like:

- [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.org) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - for JS programmers
- [regex101](http://regex101.com) - universally for regexes
- [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org) - for perl programemrs
- [bootply](http://www.bootply.com) - for bootstrap developers
- and so on - many others like above.

Are questions about similar sites allowed on SO, and if not, when not? Websites has (usually) only few functions, they are not complex tools as like emacs or eclipse. But, they're useful tools.

An absurd example: Google search is one of main tools for any programmers, and questions about "how to use google" are sure **not** fit to SO.

What should be the "determining view" - when vote to close and when not?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: @Pëkka e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsfiddle?sort=votes&pageSize=50 For many of them i have a _internal feeling_ than theyre ok, for some not ok... ;) (don't know how show only questions what are tagged only "jsfiddle") For example, this highly upvoted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851878/is-there-a-download-function-in-jsfiddle is not really about a _programming_.

Comment: @Pëkka Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12166380/1190388)

Comment: Google is an odd counter example as it's not "mostly used by programmers", it's used by everyone, including programmers

Comment: Care the downvoter explain what is wrong with this question?  It is answerable, not _whining_ real question. If I missed something, would be nice to know what.

Comment: @RichardTingle Of course. Therefore the scentence starts with: _An absurd example_.

Comment: There's also [webapps.se], which would probably be better for questions about websites than [su] is (although they do refer to sites that "behave like an application" in their on-topic page, but I'm not too sure what that means and they don't suggest a site for sites that don't, so I'm not really sure what belongs there), although developer-**exclusive** sites ("exclusive", not "commonly used by") are probably better suited for [so], although I'd tend to try to contact the support of that site instead in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Your example searches seem to be the existence proof.  Very few questions are closed in those tags; they are questions about programming tools, which are squarely on-topic.

The only questions that were closed on the first page of the jsfiddle tag search were

- [Why jsfiddle is not rendering at all in IE8 and previous versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260947/why-jsfiddle-is-not-rendering-at-all-in-ie8-and-previous-versions), which I've reopened,
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283257/how-does-jsfiddle-work, which is Too Broad,
- [jsFiddle could be indexed or I keep my codes private?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6286123/102937), which doesn't make any sense
- [Jsfiddle errors won't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271644/jsfiddle-errors-wont-show), which can no longer be reproduced.

and a smattering of duplicates.