# Are programming-related web apps off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

Are questions about programming-related web apps off topic for Stack Overflow?

My question about JIRA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721323/how-to-delete-or-deactivate-my-own-jira-account received two close votes with the close reason

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

with one comment saying

> Surely more relevant here: webapps.stackexchange.com

If computer software used primarily for programming is on-topic, shouldn't web apps used primarily for programming be on-topic?

One question I could find about this was [Offsite web-based tool commonly used by developers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251169/offsite-web-based-tool-commonly-used-by-developers) . I'm not familiar with the web apps being described there, but those web apps are slightly different from JIRA or Github, in that they don't have user accounts. Also, that question didn't receive much voting from the community.

I could also find https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6312/2114 on Programmers Meta, which surprisingly says that Github questions should go on the webapps stack exchange.

Comment: Regarding [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6312/27077), it may *say* that GitHub questions should go to [webapps.se], but [tag:github] questions get asked on Stack Overflow all the time, and there isn't really ***too much*** complaint about that. Stack Overflow's [on-topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that "software tools commonly used by programmers" are allowed, and you could argue that something like GitHub is a software tool, or more specially source code management tool.

Comment: Categorizing [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) similarly may be more difficult. Yes, it is a tool used by programmers, but it's more directly related to the domain of **project management**, rather than source code management. Project management is not specific to programmers, i.e. project managers and other people other than programmers can and do use JIRA.

Comment: @Cupcake From P.SE, we'd rather migrate github questions to web apps than to Stack Overflow (and have them get rejected). They may be on topic on SO, but they're also on topic on WebApps, and in either case are off topic on P.SE... so we'd rather migrate them to somewhere where they are most on topic if we are to migrate at all.

Comment: This seems strangely similar to the many Facebook questions we've gotten. Programming a Facebook app was on topic at SO, but issues with a Facebook account ("I can't access my account", "I forgot my password", "My friends can't access this part of my wall") were not. How does "I can't delete or deactivate my JIRA account" differ?

Comment: @KenWhite JIRA is a "[tool] used primarily for programming". Facebook isn't.

Comment: I'm missing how administration of your account is programming related, though. Visual Studio is a programming tool, but not being able to figure out how to find it in the Start menu isn't a programming question.

Comment: @KenWhite That's not really a fair comparison. He's asking how to do something through the tool itself. If he were asking for its URL your analogy would be valid.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site used as tool primarily by programmers, but you won't find account usage questions on SO, they have another site set up for that

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I saw your answer. I'm not sure I agree, but I am sure you're more familiar with Jira than I am, so I stand corrected.

Answer (score 64):

I had a whole "that question belongs on WebApps" answer prepared, then I went looking for Jira questions on other sites.

- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira) has 8 Jira questions.
- [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira) has 17.
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira) has 18.

Meanwhile, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira) has over 1600. It's pretty clear where you're most likely to get an answer to a Jira question. There just aren't a lot of people on other sites asking/answering questions about it. I think any questions about both Jira and GitHub should be allowed on Stack Overflow under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" clause in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is the most consistent answer we can give; if we really start parsing out individual aspects of JIRA as acceptable and others as not, we're just going to create havoc and unexpected behavior.  So while there's not a great fit, this is about the best we can do (short of JIRA taking off and having its own Stack Exchange site).

Comment: ...and you are a Mod on SO, and not on the alternative sites. :-)

Comment: I generally agree, but this specific question really stinks of being a Jira customer support issue.

Comment: But be aware that of the 1600 questions  asked about JIRA, a lot of them are about the APIs, plugin development, query language, deployment errors, ... .

Comment: @BradKoch It sounds like he's asking how to delete an account himself, not for someone to do it for him.

Comment: @DimitriM Yes, but I'd wager that not all of them are, just as not all the Visual Studio and Eclipse questions are 100% about development either. It's just easier to have all the questions that we can about those tools here, rather than splitting them between SO and SU.

Comment: GitHub is a tool used commonly by programmers, but asking how to update your billing info is not on topic for SO, same as asking about deleting your JIRA account

Comment: @random a more 1 to 1 comparison, neither is asking how to delete you Github account :)

Comment: Under this rule, where does a question about changing a JIRA or GitHub account's email go to? Of the user asking, not programmatically, not through the API, not through the command line, not via AJAX, but something as updating the email linked to your account? and @geo

Comment: @random If they're asking an admin to do it for them, that's a questions that should be directed to GitHub or Atlassian (or whoever is administering Jira). If they're asking how it's done through the tool, I think they should be allowed to ask it on SO. (Of course they can feel free to ask on Web Apps, I just don't see a lot of people there answering GitHub/Jira questions.)

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's only twice as many, not 100 times as many. See the difference?

Comment: @Chris My answer doesn't claim that there are any administrative questions about JIRA at all.

Comment: Your answer makes the case to ask admin questions about web apps on SO because that's where the tag numbers are

Answer (score 5):

It's too bad you didn't think to write "Please delete my JIRA account and all its associated user accounts. My name is blah blah. My contact is blah blah. My account number is..." after having clicked on that big [Get Support] button at the bottom of the page you [linked to](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=415370105).

[Atlassian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian) is a web-based business. Those types of business make it very easy to start a business relationship with them, but then can make it difficult for you to cancel that same said business relationship (and delete such business/organizational accounts). And that is precisely why, sometimes the only way to delete such accounts is to contact the business directly, and to keep on insisting (if they start giving you the run-around).

As to Stack Overflow itself, it isn't perfect. The categories aren't perfect. And sometimes the Stack Overflow users, who are developers themselves (myself included), can lose patience with someone who appears to have asked a simple question (especially if that person has a huge reputation to begin with and seems to have been a developer for a while, and therefore could have answered his own question himself with a tiny little bit more effort).

Comment: While I don't necessarily disagree with your "answer", the snarky assessment of Atlassian is unnecessary and distracts from your point.

Comment: You can characterize my assessment anyway you want. For what it's worth, I did it this way too with my own web-based business. Database integrity, backup/recovery, and historical accounting/invoicing purposes are all good reasons for not wanting to delete an organizational/company account. As a web developer, I didn't maintain a separate database for my accounting, nor did I develop the initial system to make it easy to delete an organizational account without needing to delete its primary key. In hindsight, that's probably what I should have done right from the get go, but I didn't.

Comment: And based on my experience with other web-based businesses as customer/user, I believe many other businesses designed their web-based system the same way I did. Deleting accounts is just not something that someone designs upfront when making a web-based application.

Comment: @kbrimington while perhaps a little distracting from the meta question, it's helpful to my SO question, because it gives an explanation as to *why* there isn't the ability for me to delete my account.

Answer (score 3):

It's the difference between topic and scope. It's on topic, but not necessarily in scope.

For web apps it comes to how you're using it.

It's in scope for the site if you do things such as:

- interacting with its API
- things with actual code

It's out of scope and belongs on a site like Web Applications if it's more on the side of:

- about how to work the user interface
- anything to do with your profile or account
- general user support

For apps like JIRA, GitHub or even jsFiddle, they might be used primarily by programmers, but questions about how to delete an account, billing or the like do not belong on Stack Overflow.

Another example is if you wanted to update your Facebook profile cover photo. You'd ask that on Web Applications, even though the Facebook SDK is used primarily by developers. Same overall product, different parts of the machine.

If it's a question you'd ask Technical Support (say when using the app's ticket/help system) then it would be on Stack Overflow.
If it was Account/Billing Support, then it would belong on Web Applications.

Just because a tag exists on one site doesn't mean it should accept all questions.

Context matters, not tag counts.

Comment: "Context matters, not tag counts." +1. By the way, not all the questions about "general user support" are "on-scope" on [webapps.se], i.e. questions about company/web app policies, technologies, account recovery beyond self-service and some other things that only company agents can answer