# Why was "Extract email address from gmail message body" migrated from SO to Web Applications"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migrated-questions

[Extract email address from gmail message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549608/extract-email-address-from-gmail-message-body) is on topic both on SO and on Web Applications but it has more chances to reach knowlable people on SO as the core of the question is related to programming rather than to knowledge about using the related web applications.

The question includes a link to a post on Web Applications but also the code and what the OP tried. On SO the question includes the following tags

[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) [google-spreadsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-api)

One important tag that is missing is [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script); other missing tags are [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) and perhaps [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

[email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email), [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) and [google-spreadsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-api) could be removed to make room for the missing tags.

While the OP asked to move the question to Web Applications, IMHO it should not be moved just for that reason and neither because the original code was taken from that site.

Comment: @Gimby my concern was that the question was moved prior to fix the tags. I tried to do say that on the question. On Web Applications the tags were fixed. As a side note the OP hasn't joined Web Applications yet.

Comment: @pnuts I VtC to reject the migration not to close as duplicate

Comment: @pnuts : The question was deleted few hours ago by Community as a "dead question" by the other hand, there is a similar question by "another user" with the same user name -> [Unable to collect email address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114281/88163)

Comment: Related: [Are programming-related web apps off-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260539/1595451)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The user flagged it to be migrated, it seemed like a reasonable question without an answer already on SO, so it was migrated.

You say yourself it's on-topic on Web Apps, correct? It sat on SO for almost a month without an answer, if there hasn't been an answer here in that time and the OP requested it to be moved to a site where it is on-topic, then there's no issue; the effect is the same as if the asker had just deleted it and re-asked it on a different site.

When handling flags you make judgment calls. Which I did based on the fact that the OP requested it, it's on-topic for Web Apps, there were no answers, and it's been around for a month.

You're more than welcome to VtC on web apps if you don't feel it belongs there, but you're also welcome to edit the post into shape. Try not to get hung up on migration; focus on what is appropriate for the question given its content.