# Why is the wrong answerer shown on the front page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363958/why-extract-email-address-from-gmail-message-body-was-migrated-from-so-to-web) was answered by Taryn, there are no deleted answers. Why does it say it was answered by Shog9 on the front page?

> [image: screenshot of front page]

Comment: Because his awesomeness ...

Comment: I guess because Bluefeet changed her name the system got confused and took the next best ♦

Comment: @Floern Shhhh, you're giving away all of our secrets.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because Shog9 with his magic tools, converted all my comments on the question into an answer, and then changed the owner of the answer from him to me.

He is wizard, I say, a wizard.

[image]

Comment: Cache miss between username and gravatar.

Comment: The question is, why did you post your answer as a string of comments in the first place? With your experience, you should know that comments are not the place for answers!

Comment: @MrLister Because I was in the midst of other things and didn't have time for a full answer, but since I was the one who migrated I commented initially thinking it would have settled it.