# What does a developer tools question need to be welcome on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I [recently saw and answered a question on SO about Azure Boards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138020/how-to-view-all-work-item-types-on-kanban-board/75275306#75275306).

The question was later closed, but I'm not sure why. The close reason was that it is "not about programming or software development" but ["software tools [primarily/commonly] used by programmers" is included in that definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Like it or not, Azure Boards (and Azure DevOps as a whole) is a tool which developers often find themselves required to use by their orgs and is explicitly focused towards developers. We even have [a whole tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-boards) for Azure Boards questions where many of the questions are not closed.

Presumably, therefore, I'm missing something which makes this question not about a developer software tool (or there is a precondition to questions that are about developer software tools that I missed). I'm wondering what it was so I can make sure that I answer admissible questions and give users feedback on how to improve in the future.

Comment: Kanban boards aren't specific to software development. Neither are the more general task boards.

Comment: Aside from that, questions should be specific to the way that a programmer would use the tool. We wouldn't take a question about, say, how to download a GitHub project intended for use as a standalone, end-user application, run its setup scripts, and use the program. But we would take one about, say, configuring git to upload to GitHub automatically under certain conditions.

Comment: Pointing out that there are closable questions that aren't closed is not a good argument. We know there are huge numbers of such questions. The number of people closing closable questions has always been insufficient compared to the number of questions being asked.

Comment: A tag existing for a product doesn't make any question about it on-topic either. [[tag:google-maps]] has a tag, but that doesn't mean *anything* about Google Maps is on topic; you couldn't post a question about how to ensure that the route you get avoids tolls when asking for one on your android phone, for example. The question still needs to adhere to the site's on-topic rules.

Comment: Related meta Q&A about JIRA: [Are programming-related web apps off-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260539/are-programming-related-web-apps-off-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: There is no real consensus how to handle these types of questions, in my experience. Because Azure falls within the realm of a tool used by software developers (whether we want it or not), some people will treat it as if ANY question about Azure then becomes valid but others will stick to the "must be a practical programming problem" bit. Which is in the rules for sure, but it also creates pretty big tug o' wars about what is a programming problem or not. In the end it all depends on which pair of eyes lands on the question. The next question that is not a programming problem might stay open.

Comment: Two times "to be" in the title?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [kanban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kanban) tag guidance, italic emphasis mine:

> Kanban is a method for developing software products and processes with an emphasis on just-in-time delivery while not overloading the software developers. **Please note:** This is *exclusively for programming questions*; methodology questions should be directed to Software Engineering SE, and *project management questions should go to Project Management SE*.

Answer (score 6):

I'll go slightly more specific than Karl's laconic (and good!) answer, since there's always a nuance in this context.

When approaching a tool, the best thing to think of would be, "Is this tool something a developer would normally be using in the context of programming?"

Let's take Git for example.  In the context of programming, a developer may or may not choose to use Git specifically, but a developer would likely choose some variant of version control.  So, it makes sense that a question about Git would be on-topic here.

Jira has a nuance to it as well given that it has an API and you can do automation-like things with it.  If you're asking about how to hook into Jira to perform X thing with Y API call, then you're likely on-topic.  If you're asking about how to configure your board so it picks up your branches from GitHub, you're probably off-topic, since a *developer* doesn't need the linking between Jira and GitHub, but a project manager-type person might.

In this case, using Azure Boards explicitly, unless you were asking about how to build an integration with it or had a challenge in accessing its API, there's a very high chance that it's off-topic here.  Not everyone uses a board to organize their work (***much*** to my chagrin and constant pain), and not everyone *needs* a board to just write code (again, I'm experiencing a lot of pain with this in particular).

Comment: It can also work the other way. Where I work jira is used so dogmatically to define work, people actually stop working together to solve problems and major decisions that should have been discussed before implementation get discussed during the merge request review. Madness.